# Making cell editable through generic method

Tags: java, generics, javafx, cell

i have this method :

```
  private static <S,T> TableColumn<S,T> createColumn(String title, Function<S, Property<T>> property) {

        TableColumn<S,T> col = new TableColumn<>(title);

        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));

        col.setOnEditCommit(edit -> {
            S rowValue = edit.getRowValue();
            property.apply(rowValue).setValue(edit.getNewValue());
        });

        return col ;
    }
```

with this method i create column and add it to the tableview;

```
 TableColumn<Model, String> name = createColumn("name", Model::model_nameProperty);
```

data loads fine and columns present values ok.
But i cant edit cell of column,

so i tried adding cellFactory to my generic method :

```
      private static <S,T> TableColumn<S,T> createColumn(String title, Function<S, Property<T>> property) {

        TableColumn<S,T> col = new TableColumn<>(title);

        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));
      col.setCellFactory(c-> new TableCell());
        col.setOnEditCommit(edit -> {
            S rowValue = edit.getRowValue();
            property.apply(rowValue).setValue(edit.getNewValue());
        });

        return col ;
    }
```

but this does not work at all, then i removed :
col.setCellFactory(c-> new TableCell());

and used my original method(first method from this thread);
but i added

```
name.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
```

and now it works. but is there any way to add this

```
name.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
```

to my first, generic method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn()` has a return type of `Callback<TableColumn<S,String>` which means it can only be used if the column type is String. This is because it is a TextField so it only really knows how to deal with the String type, just like a checkbox only does boolean type.

This would force you to change your entire method to use String instead of T to get it to compile, i.e.

```
private static <S> TableColumn<S, String> createColumn(String title, Function<S, Property<String>> property) {

    TableColumn<S, String> col = new TableColumn<>(title);

    col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));

    col.setOnEditCommit(edit -> {
        S rowValue = edit.getRowValue();
        property.apply(rowValue).setValue(edit.getNewValue());
    });

    col.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());

    return col;
}
```

However forTableColumn() can take an optional StringConverter which allow it to deal with non-String types..., You'll still to to provide some kind of conversion between String and T, in both directions... Whether this can be done 'generically' is debatable.

```
col.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new StringConverter<T>() {

    @Override
    public T fromString(String arg0) {
        return null; // <== need to map back..
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(T object) {
        return object.toString();
    }

}));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped me, i am still decide which approach to use, but your answer pointed me in right direction. Thanks!